# Mail forwarding after graduation

Tags: email

It's been less than a year since I graduated and my university e-mail address is still active. Therefore, I have been able to receive invitations to review papers (presumably from my publications).

As per university policy, the e-mail account will be terminated soon. They offer an alumni.xyz.edu account but do not offer any forwarding for the xyz.edu account.

Apart from petitioning the university to change this ludicrous policy, has anyone else experience this problem?

Comment: Incidentally, I used to think this sort of policy was impossible to justify (offering, say, ten years of forwarding would cost almost nothing, and the inability to reuse these addresses in the meantime would not be such a great loss). However, a few years ago a prominent US math department caught someone fraudulently claiming to have a current affiliation with the department and using their old but still active e-mail address as evidence. I doubt this happens often, but it's a genuine downside to allowing forwarding, and I can understand why the potential for confusion worries administrators.

Comment: Whatever one may think of this policy, I think it is fairly standard - whether from a university or any other workplace. (well, most commercial organisations wouldn't give you a year - if the address still existed the day after you left, it would be redirecting to somebody else)

Answer (score 1):

***Policy Note***: Yes, this is happening all the time. However, each university policy might be different on its students/staff data. Also, might be different in each case, based on the level of education. For example they might do this for their previous postgraduate students; but not their undergraduates.

You need to send an email to the system admin of the university and ask him/her *very nicely* to forward all the upcoming emails to your current account. Something like following:

> Dear Mr/Miss X,
>
> I was a student/staff at the university from 20?? to 20??. My university email account was me@uni.asd.edu. Could you please forward all the upcoming emails to this address to my alumni/current email address (e.g., alumni@x.edu/currentemail@site.com)?
>
> Kind Regards,
>
> Me

Comment: Tried and failed. Response: *this is part of xyz policy and cannot be changed*. Yay.

Comment: @Jacob All people I knew from the past, including myself could do this, by sending a very polite email to the system admin of the university.

Comment: You can also ask for an alias to forward your non-alumni email to your alumni account and then manually forward from your alumni account to your personal email.